# Best way to load 24-bit BGR image from memory to ID2D1Bitmap1

Tags: optimization, bitmap, directx-11

I have a BGR 24-bit image in memory as continuous buffer (represented by `cv::Mat`, in case it may be of any help). I would like to load it to `ID2D1Bitmap1` bitmap for 2D rendering. I have the following working code (showing a pseudo-code here):

```
IWICImagingFactory::CreateBitmapFromMemory(GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR);
IWICFormatConverter::Initialize(GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGB);
ID2D1DeviceContext::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap;
```

This works fine, the main issue being the time it takes: 20-40 milliseconds, which is too long for my application. I am looking for ways to optimize the process.

I, probably, can save the creation time of the `ID2D1Bitmap1` by doing this once, and then loading the converted image from memory using `CopyFromMemory`, but still the conversion itself takes a large amount of time. One way could be loading the raw BGR buffer to GPU memory, and converting it to *native* RGBA format on the GPU itself, but I have no idea how start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second idea is exactly the direction you should go.  Create the `ID2D1Bitmap`(s) once, convert the buffer (more on that below), and use `CopyFromMemory`.  I do something very similar in an app which provides a preview of a connected webcam (which may have one of various formats).  Some cameras will deliver the images in MJPEG, YUY2, etc.

That app uses `MediaFoundation`, and an `IMFTransform` to convert the buffer.  The `IMFTransform` in this case is an instance of `CLSID_CColorConvertDMO` (which uses SIMD registers/instructions when possible).  However, prior to completing that, I tested with my own conversion code (which was CPU bound, and performed so-so), and another solution with `HLSL` and `DirectCompute` (performed well, but handled only one format).  In the end I chose `CLSID_CColorConvertDMO` to handle the various types of input, but if you only have one known type, you may choose to use the `HLSL` solution (although it will cause you to have to write the conversion code, and setup the 'views' of the data).

However, if you choose the `MediaFoundation` route, you can use an `IMFTransform` without all of the rest of the graph (source, sink, etc).  After creating the `CLSID_CColorConvertDMO` instance, and setting the input and output types (format, frame size, etc), create an [IMFSample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702192(v=vs.85).aspx) (using [MFCreateSample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702276(v=vs.85).aspx)), and an [IMFMediaBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696261(v=vs.85).aspx) (using [MFCreateMemoryBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695212(v=vs.85).aspx)) to the sample (using [IMFSample::AddBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697465(v=vs.85).aspx)), then all that is necessary is to call [ProcessInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703131(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ProcessOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704014(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert the buffer (create all items upfront).  This may sound like a lot, but if done correctly, your cpu utilization will not have a noticeable impact, and you will achieve the performance you are looking for, even for capture cards which often deliver large frames at 60+ FPS (having used DataPath and Blackmagic capture cards in the past).

Good luck.  I am certain you will crush it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I am not familiar with MediaFoundation (yet :) What will make this approach more efficient than conversion using `IWICFormatConverter`? Will it do the conversion on the GPU? Or will it save some GPU-memory copying?

Comment: WIC is convenient and flexible, but not designed for continuous real-time conversion, and is usually CPU bound.  And of course HLSL will be GPU bound, but if you create the buffer views upfront, the memory copy will be your only overhead.  MediaFoundation will use the GPU when configured properly (I cover this in detail in some of my other answers), and the above steps will be GPU bound with your formats.

Comment: OK, will start digging into it, sounds like a good direction, thanks.